# Proof of the fact that the decreasing limit of continuous increasing functions is right continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a proof of the following statement:

> Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of continuous and increasing functions. If $f_n(x) \searrow f(x)$, as $n \rightarrow +\infty$, then $f(x)$ is right continuous.

My *attempt* to prove it:

Suppose that $f(x)$ is **not** right continuous; i.e., $\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} f(x + \delta) \neq f(x)$. Then, $\exists \epsilon > 0$, such that, $\forall \delta > 0$, $|f(x + \delta) - f(x)| > \epsilon$. It follows that:

$$
\begin{align}
\epsilon & < |f(x + \delta) - f(x) + f_n(x) - f_n(x) + f_n(x + \delta) - f_n(x + \delta)| \leq \\ 
&\leq |f(x + \delta) - f_n(x + \delta)| + |f_n(x) - f(x)| + |f_n(x + \delta) - f_n(x)|.
\end{align}
$$

The first two terms can be controlled by choosing a sufficiently large $n$ s.t. $|f(x + \delta) - f_n(x + \delta)|$ and $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ are $< \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, while the third term can be controlled by choosing a $\delta$ s.t. $|f_n(x + \delta) - f_n(x)| = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Implying that $\epsilon < \frac{3 \epsilon}{3} = \epsilon$, which is an absurdity, completing the proof.

Since I'm not very convinced if I made something wrong, my question is: Is this a valid proof? If it is not, what should I do in order to correctly prove the described statement?

EDIT: as pointed out by @TheoreticalEconomist, it is necessary an inequality (instead of a "$=$", as it was written before) for controlling the first two terms. But even though, I'm not sure if the presented proof is correct: the fact that $f_n$ decreases to $f$, as $n \rightarrow +\infty$, is being used at the "two terms" part; however, the third term is still a problem $-$ somehow it should be justified by the $(f_n)$ characteristics.

EDIT 2: I think it is correct because: 1) chosen $n = \max(n_0, n_1)$, s.t. $|f(x + \delta) - f_n(x + \delta)|$ and $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ are $< \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, it is possible to choose a convenient $\delta$ s.t. $|f_n(x + \delta) - f_n(x)| = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ (notice that, before that point, $\delta$ was not chose yet); and 2) the hyphothesis of $(f_n)$ being a sequence of increasing function (implying that $f$ is a increasing function as well) is indeed needed $-$ recall that $|f(x + \delta) - f(x)| > \epsilon$ has to be satisfied (otherwise, it would not be true). Which, if I'm not wrong, eliminates all potential problems.

FINAL EDIT: for a proper proof, please refer to the Tom's answer.

Comment: Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess the potential difficulty with this proof is that when you choose $n$ so that $\vert f(x+\delta) - f_n (x+\delta) \vert < \epsilon / 3$ and $\vert f_n(x) - f(x) \vert < \epsilon / 3$ (I think you actually want inequalities here), you need $\delta$ fixed, but then you also need to choose $\delta$ so that $\vert f_n (x+\delta) - f_x(x) \vert < \epsilon / 3$, keeping $n$ fixed. And I'm not sure you can choose $\delta$ and $n$ simultaneously without showing that $f_n$ actually converges uniformly (or something like it)...

Comment: Is your notation correct ? I think $\searrow $  means converges from above (which would be difficult for increasing functions). To signify convergence from below use $\nearrow $

Comment: As @TheoreticalEconomist points out uniform convergence is required. See examples here https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690707?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents and also proof for uniform convergence here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem

Comment: @Tom Uniform convergence would be sufficient, but not necessary, as your first link actually demonstrates. The OP's proof makes no use of the facts that each $f_n$ is monotone, and that the convergence is actually monotone, so my guess is those properties are needed to show that $f$ is right-continuous.

Comment: @Tom Also, I think that the OP means that each $f_n$ is increasing in $x$, but $f_{n+1} \le f_n$, so you have convergence from above.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist. Ah, thanks. Working through the counterexamples in the links I gave I can find something for lack of left continuity, but not right. So it could be correct - but I haven't found a proof.

Comment: In fact, uniform convergence would solve my problem, but yeah, I'm not sure if it's a necessary additional hypothesis. I'm still working on try to figure this out, and I'll update it here if a find a proper solution.

Comment: Even if $f$ is continuous then $|f(x + \delta) - f(x)| > \epsilon$ can be satisfied for large enough $\delta$, so to prove discontinuity this must hold for all $\delta$. Then without uniform convergence I don't think you can say that you can choose $n$ to simultaneously satisfy $\vert f(x+\delta) - f_n (x+\delta) \vert < \epsilon / 3$ and $\vert f(x) - f_n (x) \vert < \epsilon / 3$?

Comment: @Tom, I think EDIT 2 answers your concerns.

Comment: I don't think your edits fix things. Note your proof makes no use of the fact that $f_n$ is increasing or that each $f_n$ converges to $f$ from above. Thus, your proof could just as well be applied to a sequence of functions converging pointwise (not necessarily from above/below) to some other function. This means that if your proof were correct, it would establish that the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous. There are well-known counterexamples to this claim. See the links that Tom has provided.

Comment: It seems that generally we aren't happy with your proof, but that the statement could still be true. Let's have a bit of background - is this your own conjecture or have you seen it asserted somewhere ?

Comment: Hey, @Tom! Please refer to: https://www.ihes.fr/~duminil/publi/2017percolation.pdf $-$ the result was used at page 13 and stated (as exercise: n.19) at page 14.

Comment: Proving this would probably be the least of my problems in these notes ! Their author does come up on Google and his web page does give a contact address. I've found most people very helpful in this regard. If you get an answer before anyone else figures it out please post it.

Comment: Yeah, these notes discuss Percolation, which is a non-common subject. But as you can see, the theorem itself is independent of the peculiarities of the subject. Anyway, if I figure this out, I'll post the proper proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

At a point $x \in [x, x']$  in the domain of $f$ there is $f_n$ with $f_n(x)  < f(x) + \epsilon /2$

By continuity and increasing of $f_n$ there is $ y_n > x$ and $y_n \in [x, x']$  such that for $x + \delta \in [x, y_n] $ then $ f_n(x + \delta)  < f_n(x) + \epsilon / 2$.

Then $|f(x + \delta) - f(x)| =  f(x + \delta) - f(x)$ since $f$ is increasing (easily proved).
$f(x + \delta) \le f_n(x + \delta)$ since the sequence is decreasing to $f$.
$ |f(x + \delta) - f(x)| \le f_n(x + \delta) - f(x)$
$ |f(x + \delta) - f(x)| < f_n(x) + \epsilon / 2 - f(x) < f(x) + \epsilon /2 + \epsilon / 2 - f(x) = \epsilon $.

So for any $x + \delta \in [x, y_n] $ then $|f(x + \delta) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ and $f$ is right continuous.

(Note: the proof makes use of $f_n$ being continuous and increasing as well as the sequence decreasing to $f$ - in the end it wasn't that difficult).

Comment: Tom, you nailed it! Thank you for your (and Theoretical Economist's) help.

Comment: @André Glad it came out - stay on the site (and maybe fill out your profile).

Comment: Well, glad to see this sorted; the lack of a proof was bugging me. Though, I don't quite get the first line, since $x \in [x,x^\prime]$ reads like a tautology, so that probably isn't what you meant. Otherwise, nice proof!

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Maybe badly expressed - need $x$ to be in an interval which extends to the right in the domain of $f$. The domain isn't specified, but need to have meaning for the right limit at $x$.

Comment: I suppose you mean $x$ should be in the interior of the domain of $f$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist. Or it could be the left boundary of the domain.